# Android : Drawer Layout's Child views such as textviews dosen't show properties like textcolor etc

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SlidingMenu" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

<!--     <FrameLayout -->
<!--         android:id="@+id/content_frame" -->
<!--         android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!--         android:layout_height="match_parent" > -->
<!--     </FrameLayout> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="TextView" 
            android:text/>                           // Problem Location
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#00FFCC"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am using a DrawerLayout and I have a child view to it but eclipse content assist is not showing properties associated to it, for ex- text view dosen't show color,textsize, layout margin properties. I can hard code them and that works also but then content assist stops working for the entire Xml.What could be the possible reason behind it. Here's the actual screen shot.

[image]

Comment: try setting those properties anyways. Or restart IDE.

Comment: tried restarting IDE but to no vain

Comment: Try just writing it anyway.

Comment: as I have mentioned I am doing that, but the real pain starts after that because control assists stops working for the entire XMl later on